# Django rest framework - no such table

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create an API endpoint on my Django project to retrieve data from my frontend.

I'm using two DBs on my django project, the first one is a SQLite DB, the second one is a MongoDB database, the data i need to retrieve is on MongoDB.

Here is my model:

```
class tst(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ticker = models.FloatField()

    def save(self): # ALL the signature

        super(Trade, self).save(using='dbtwo')
```

Here is my view:

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
```

And the url:

```
path('tst/', views.tstList.as_view()),
```

Everything is alright here but when i try to open the API from my browser, i keep getting the following error:

```
OperationalError at /tst/
no such table: main_tst
```

I think this happens because it tries to look for the table `tst` on the first SQLite database, instead of looking for it on the MongoDB one. Is there any way to solve this? I thought that adding `using='dbtwo'` would do it, but it's not the right solution.

Every advice is appreciated!

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the database that you are using in the queryset for your API view

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.using('dbtwo').all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
```

Even better than this, if the model will only ever use the other database, you can [set up a router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) so that you do not have to set "using" every time

```
class MyRouter:

    def db_for_read(model, **hints):
        if model == tst:
            return 'dbtwo'

    def db_for_write(model, **hints):
        if model == tst:
            return 'dbtwo'

# In your settings
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.MyRouter']
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, i just learned about routers and i'm going to add them! Thanks again!